# migrating any windows program to another pc (without installer GUI)

Tags: windows, installation, installation-package, migrating

I am looking for a way to remotely install a program to other computer units running Windows on the fly  ,without the need of running the installer steps on each computer  (next,next,finish...)  all over again , .exe installers don't usually have an easy way to do this without using the GUI installer.
a solution that i came up with , running the installer on a single pc
and try to trace each file the installer adds (location,file names,registry files) using FileSystemWatcher then copy these files and send them to the desired hosts that need the program installed with the location of each file will this work ? is there any easier implementation

the problem with FileSystemWatcher that although it detectes which files have been added,edited or deleted its not capable to tell which process did the change ,Why would i need to know ?,other programs depends alot on files and will keep editing them so i need to isolate the installer process to easily study how its functioning and what files are added..
 the only way that i know to overcome this problem is developing a file system filter driver...

please give me your opinion or some recommendations on which is the best way to do this ,sorry for my bad english .

Comment: This isn't really a programming question. It's about network deployment, which is a server/administration related question. You can probably find an existing answer to a similar problem on either [su] or [sf].

Comment: When you ask this question on another site, provide information on what you are trying to install, the OS and user features, or your question will be closed there as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Almost every modern installer has some way to perform a silent install.  You may need to do some digging to find the answers, or ask the publisher.  Try running the installer with /? as a command line switch and see what it tells you.

Comment: you are right ! but i need this to work with any installer not a specific installer/program

Comment: Then what you need is a repackager.  Such products already exist and buying something out of the box would probably be better/faster than rolling your own.